# Where do I go after delivering the letter to Steven in Alpha Sapphire?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Playing Pokémon Alpha Sapphire, I gave the letter to Steven and talked toMr Briney, got 2 badges and I’m stuck. What do I do now? I can’t get to Verdanturf or Mauville city (no bike or Rocks Smash)

Comment: Did you already go through the Granite Cave? What is the current route or city you are stuck in?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Right now we need a few more details to help you. What have you tried doing to progress in the game so far? Have you read any game walkthroughs yet to check the next place to go?

Comment: Where is the granite cave located at?

Comment: I went to slateport and route 110 and I can’t figure out where else to go bc I can’t go on the bike route to mauville and I don’t have rock smash so I can’t get to verdanturf

Comment: I would put your additional comment into the question to make it more specific and clear - that will help future people looking at this question to figure out where to go.

Answer (score 1):

After beating the Rustboro Gym and helping the Devon employee, you meet Mr. Briney. After that, you'll be able to sail with him to and from Dewford Town. This is where you deliver the letter to Steve (in the cave) and compete in the Fighting type Gym. After this, Mr. Briney can sail you Slateport city, where your journey continues.